# Cross compiler installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling

I would like to install `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` on my ubuntu virtual machine. 
After command `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` the instalation process complete successfully but after that i can't use it.
I get an error `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi: command not found`. How to run it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`arm-linux-gnueabi` in this case is prefix

Compiler itself so may be named `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` or even more precise like `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7` (or 4.8 or so)